# cursor sql problems

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, cursor

why wont it display more than one result? Also i'm getting this error message"Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'fetch_status' to data type int" whats wrong with my code?

```
  Declare [plzwork] cursor
for 
Select * from [itsthegoodtable]

Where [Methodofpayment] = 'pd'

---open cursor

Open [plzwork]

Fetch next from [plzwork]

while 'fetch_status' = 0

fetch next from [plzwork]

close [plzwork]

deallocate [plzwork]
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: USE `@@FETCH_STATUS` instead of `'fetch_status'`.  I would also expect a conversion error.

Comment: Another issue is that you aren't setting any variables from your cursor query.  typically you would see FETCH NEXT FROM [plzwork] int @somevariable.

Answer (score 0):

Your `while` condition is comparing a string, that happens to contain "fetch_status" to an integer.  Perhaps you mean:

```
while fetch_status = 0
```

Your code sort of looks like SQL Server.  In that case, you want:

```
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
```

I also strongly recommend indenting your code correctly and using `begin`/`end` around the `while` to prevent unintentional mistakes.

Comment: i need the ' around fetch_status otherwise i get an invalid column name error ok so

Comment: according to this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RHRjLd0bEaQ on 4:51 when its set to 0 it should always be fetching the next record